How to connect from NestJS to Kafka microservice inside Docker container
I have an application in NestJS
It runs in Docker
I want to move some functionality to a microservice. For this I decided to use Kafka.
Here is an example of a Docker Compose file:
a-microservice:
    build:
      context: ../back-a-microservice
      dockerfile: ../back-a-microservice/Dockerfile
    container_name: a-microservice
    env_file: ../back/.env
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - back
      - kafka1
    restart: always
    command: npm run start:migrate:dev

  kafka1:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,EXTERNAL://kafka1:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka1:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS=2
      - KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    volumes:
      - volume-kafka-1:/bitnami/kafka
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - back
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
    driver: local
  volume-kafka-1:
    driver: local

Here is an example of initialization in NestJS:
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: {
        client: {
          brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
        },
        consumer: {
          groupId: 'a-consumer',
        },
      },
    },
  );
  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();

Here is an example of package.json in NestJS:
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.3.8",
    "kafkajs": "^2.2.4"
  },

This is the error I get when connecting:
2024-04-24 19:04:35 [Nest] 93  - 04/24/2024, 4:04:35 PM   ERROR [ServerKafka] ERROR [Connection] Connection error:  {"timestamp":"2024-04-24T16:04:35.795Z","logger":"kafkajs","broker":"localhost:9092","clientId":"nestjs-consumer-server","stack":"AggregateError: \n    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)\n    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7)"}
2024-04-24 19:04:35 [Nest] 93  - 04/24/2024, 4:04:35 PM   ERROR [ServerKafka] ERROR [BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection error:  {"timestamp":"2024-04-24T16:04:35.797Z","logger":"kafkajs","retryCount":0,"retryTime":248}

I can't figure out what the cause is.
Thanks!
I've tried reassigning to other ports, I've also tried specifying not localhost but kafka1 from the docker compose file - all this fails.
A separate restart of the microservice in docker after starting the whole application does not work either
Kafka is working well in container
...
2024-04-24 19:28:41 [2024-04-24 16:28:41,579] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
2024-04-24 19:28:41 [2024-04-24 16:28:41,581] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9094. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
...


Each container is its own localhost, so that's not going to be the right thing to connect to Kafka in a separate container (and similarly your database).  kafka1:9092, using the Compose service name as the host name, should work; what error do you get when you try that?

@DavidMaze, thank you! I'm changed to client: {
brokers: ['kafka1:9092'],
retry: {
retries: 10,
},
}                   and           - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094      and      depends_on:
postgres:
condition: service_started
restart: true               and now this is works well.    But by some reason docker ignore this depends_on and I receive errors first before Kafka starts well, but after service works

Also see Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y – just depends_on: on its own doesn't ensure the preceding service is actually running.
